# VisualStudio installs "Shared components, tools, and SDKs" only on C: drive

Tags: hard-drive, visual-studio

So I already looked up on the Microsoft page how to fix the problem that it will just install to my C: drive but that didn't help. I tried what they said, what was to just set the other 2 options (Visual Studio IDE and Download Cache) on another drive and installed it but it still filled up my C: drive. The "Shared components, tools, and SDKs" alsoe never changed from the C: drive on where it tells me where it will be installed and even though its a field like the other changeable two I cant change it. Ive also put the thing what they just call "Location" on my desired drive. How can I fix that?

Comment: My C: is an SSD and has 1GB left after only the packages I really really need but I cannot install anything more than that and I cant risk running my C: full of data. Every program I use is installed on another drive only windows is on C:

Comment: Pretty much between both of that but I have only ever programmed inside of an engine not without one (Except minor console applications) but why is that important? I just wanna install an IDE

Comment: I would love to do as I wish but I cant figure out how sadly

Comment: It appears there is no way around the other files going to the C drive (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7160ef-505e-4c48-a1aa-78e778c13ee0/install-visual-studio-2017-in-d-drive?forum=vssetup)  `Note: this won't change location of all files, but only of those which can be (by design) installed onto different location. Be warned that there is many shared components which will be installed into shared repositories on drive C: without any possibility to change their path.`

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is having the issue of changing this path then I have found the answer.

1. Type "regedit" in the search on your Windows 10 PC (or in your run
   if lower version I think)
2. Navigate to the following: Computer / HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SOFTWARE / Microsoft / Visual Studio / Setup
3. Double click the file "SharedInstallationPath" and change the value in there.

Be **very** careful in the registry editor

Comment: "and change the value in there" - Change it to what exactly?

Comment: Thanks! There is a big tho: On the visual installer it still shows that the components will be installed on the C drive... But this seems just to be a display bug

Comment: I made the registry change 'before' running the installer & it showed the 'updated/new' custom path in the dialog box (but still greyed out).

Comment: Thank you!
""""There is a big tho: On the visual installer it still shows that the components will be installed on the C drive... But this seems just to be a display bug – 
Alan
 Mar 22 '20 at 10:26""" - no, I closed installer before changing the register. The installer shows a new path for Shared Components.